# How to change the color of a SizedBox in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to **change the color** of a **SizedBox**. I'd actually like to know why I can't change the color of the column as well but I only need to change the color of my SizedBox. I am **returning** a Column in a **ListView.builder** which has a column inside that that I'd like to change the color of. Not sure why I can't change it.

My code:
If I remove the line `"color: Colors.black, "` everything works fine.

I've also **noticed** that the decoration or color: Colors.black **isn't** working **within** the **ListViewBuilder**.

```
return Column(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        height: 56.0,
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            ////Text('${today}'),
                            ////Text('${day}.'),
                            ////Text('$hour'),
                            Text('Mo'),
                            Text('18.'),
                            Text('10'),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
```

etc.

I only get the **error**:

```
"error: No named parameter with the name 'color'"
```

Comment: the error is right: `SizedBox` has no such property, most likely you need `ColoredBox` as a `child`

Comment: Thank you, this worked as well as changing it to a container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `SizedBox` with `Container`.
Container widget widget have 'height' and 'color' parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Replace Sizebox with ColoredBox

```
ColoredBox(
    color: Colors.black,
    child: ,
  )
```